# How to generate LLVM bitcode for a file using a compilation database?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I want to generate LLVM bitcode for a large number of C source files for which I have a [compilation database](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) . Is there way to invoke `clang` such that it reads the compilation database and uses the appropriate flags?

### Background

For toy programs, the command to generate LLVM bitcode is simple:

```
clang -emit-llvm -c foo.c -o foo.bc
```

However, source files in large projects require lots of additional compilation flags, including `-I`s and `-D`s and whatnot.

I want to write a script that iterates over a large number of source files and calls `clang -emit-llvm ...` on each to generate LLVM bitcode. The difficulty is that each `clang -emit-llvm ...` command has to have the flags specific to that source file. I have a compilation database for these source files, which perfectly captures the flags needed for each individual source file. **Is there a way to make `clang -emit-llvm ...` aware of my compilation database?**

One solution I've thought of is to parse the compilation database myself and find the appropriate entry for each source file, and modify the `command` entry to (a) include `-emit-llvm` and (b) change `-o foo.o` to `-o foo.bc`, and then run the command. This might work, but seems a bit hacky.

Comment: for a large complex piece of software involving generating and manipulating many bitcode files, you may want to consider the all the steps suggested by:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459800/creating-and-using-llvm-bitcode-libraries

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the compilation database yourself, you could rely on the Python binding to do so. Judging from the [test suite](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/bindings/python/tests/cindex/test_cdb.py#L37) of the binding, you could do something like:

```
cdb = CompilationDatabase.fromDirectory(kInputsDir)
cmds = cdb.getAllCompileCommands()
```

and then slightly update the content of `cmds`.